# Difference between two files in Lucene

Tags: c#, lucene, indexing, lucene.net

In Lucene in C# I am trying to find out if the index contains duplicate files or almost identical to see if it needs to be replaced with the new file. To do this I have figured a way of doing it might be to use the MoreLikeThis class, then get a list of related documents. Then after compare these related documents to see if they match the document I am adding in—say a 90% match. The program will then ask if the user if the two are duplicates and which one to keep.

1. Can this be done using Lucene? ...and is this the best way to go about doing it?
2. If this can't be done, is using the [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) the most efficient way of comparing two files to see if they have a similar match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for comparing documents with lucene you can also use TermFreqVector and saving TermVector in your index. Also you can compute Dirichlet similarity with this vecotr.